# implementing GDC with applescriptobjc

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, applescript-objc

I am making this simple ApplescriptObjC cocoa app just as an exercise for me to understand the multi treading, it is a text field and a label, I was trying to update the label in real time while typing in the text field, but it only get updated once I press enter but not in real time, any idea how I can make that work? here is the code.
Thanks

```
    script AppDelegate

    property parent : class "NSObject"
    property prgLabel: missing value
    property subjectFeild: missing value


    on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
        -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened  
    activate
  end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

    on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
        -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
        return current application's NSTerminateNow
    end applicationShouldTerminate_

    on textChange_(sender)

        set SU to subjectFeild's stringValue() as string
        prgLabel's setStringValue_(SU)

    end textChange_


end script
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Set the delegate of the textfield to be your app delegate.

2) Implement controlTextDidChange, which is called every time the text field changes during editing.

```
script AppDelegate
    property parent : class "NSObject"

    -- IBOutlets
    property theWindow : missing value
    property prgLabel: missing value
    property subjectFeild: missing value

    on applicationWillFinishLaunching:aNotification
        subjectFeild's setDelegate:me
    end applicationWillFinishLaunching_


    on controlTextDidChange:notification
        prgLabel's setStringValue:subjectFeild's stringValue()
    end

end script
```